# Drawing WPF PathFigure with outline

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing, effects

I'm trying to display a WPF `Path`-Object with the following requirements:

1. I want to have the `Path` itself displayed in a specific color and a specific thickness.
2. I want to color the outline of the `Path` with another color and thickness

**Example** (in real life the figure is more complex, with curves etc.):

[image: Example]

Is there any way to achieve this effect in WPF?

I tried to overlay two separate Path (red Path on top of blue Path), but the result does not look very smooth, especially when you have rounded corners.

I also tried using a `DropShadowEffect`, but couldn't get a clear outline like in the example.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

created by

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Geometry x:Key="pathData">M100,100 L200,100 200,150 A1,1 0 0 1 100,150 Z</Geometry>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="15" StrokeLineJoin="Round"
          Data="{StaticResource pathData}"/>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="6" StrokeLineJoin="Round"
          Data="{StaticResource pathData}"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I need to go spanish: MUY BUENO!

Comment: I admit, it looks good. I had a few problems in my case, but analyzing them I think it was because my Path was a lot thinner and it was inside a ViewBox which seemed to introduce some artifacts. But it does not seem to be a general problem with Paths. Thanks!